# It was great to meet you

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality-in-context

Do you say "It was great to meet you?" Or only "It was nice/good to meet you" are fixed phrases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, you can say **It was great to meet you**, but

> **Nice to meet you**

Is more commonly used.

Comment: Do you mean "It was nice to meet you" is more common than "It was great to meet you"?

Comment: Exactly, i hear more "It was nice to meet you"  than the other. But you can say it in either way

Comment: You can say "It was absolutely amazing and wonderful to meet you" if you really want to, but native speakers (especially British) don't usually go that far.

Comment: **Nice/good to meet you** is a polite response. **Great to meet you** is an enthusiastic response. You can use any of them. But better not say **Great/wonderful/super etc to meet you** to someone you don't particularly want to see again.